# Bertopic __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'diversity'

Tags: python

I have not made the code so I turn to you. I've been running this line of code with no problems. Until a few days ago it worked fine and now I don't know why it doesn't work.

This is the mistake

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3e2827f308dc> in <module>
    550                 print('Diga si o no (elegido el valor predeterminado para bases pequeñas.)\n')
    551 
--> 552             topic_model = BERTopic(min_topic_size=min_topic_size, #Modificar si hay errores
    553                            diversity=diversity,
    554                            top_n_words=top_n_words,

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'diversity'
```

This is the line of code

```
 topic_model = BERTopic(min_topic_size=min_topic_size, #Modificar si hay errores
                           diversity=diversity,
                           top_n_words=top_n_words, 
                           verbose=True, #Informe de resultados
                           #language="multilingual", 
                           calculate_probabilities = True, #desactivar si hay muchos datos
                           vectorizer_model = vectorizer_model,
                           embedding_model = sentence_model,
                           low_memory = low_memory
                                  ) #Añadir low_memory=True si hay muchos datos 
            print("Configuración exitosa. Cargue el archivo y corra el modelo.")
```

Could you help me please? I'm not very good at python

Comment: It seems that the definition of `BERTopic` would be relevant to this question.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the parameter diversity has been changed in this library. [Here is how it works now](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/tips_and_tricks/tips_and_tricks.html#diversify-topic-representation). You can change your code to the following:

```
from bertopic.representation import MaximalMarginalRelevance
representation_model = MaximalMarginalRelevance(diversity=diversity)
topic_model = BERTopic(min_topic_size=min_topic_size, #Modificar si hay errores
                       top_n_words=top_n_words, 
                       verbose=True, #Informe de resultados
                       calculate_probabilities = True, #desactivar si hay muchos datos
                       vectorizer_model = vectorizer_model,
                       embedding_model = sentence_model,
                       low_memory = low_memory,
                       representation_model=representation_model)
```

Comment: note: there is a typo - it should be `bertopic.representation`, not `bertopic.respresentation`

Answer (score 0):

The error says exactly what's wrong, the class `BERTopic`'s constructor i.e. `__init__` doesn't have a keyword argument called `diversity`, so you doing
`BERTopic(..., diversity=diversity, ...)` just won't work.

Comment: And what should I add? What argument?